# csv value modification for certain cells on odd rows on a particular column

Tags: python, csv

Hi I'm trying to finish this small piece of code for modifying csv files, I've got this far with some help:

edit... some more info.

> Basically what I’m looking to do is make some small changes to the csv file depending on the project and parent issue in JIRA. Python will then make the changes to the csv file before it is then read into JIRA - that’s the second part of the program I’ve not even really looked at yet.
>   I’m only looking to change the BOX-123 type cells and leave the blank ones blank.
>   But the idea of the program is that I can use it to make some small changes to a template which will then automatically create some issues in JIRA.

```
import os
import csv

project = 'Dudgeon'
parent = 'BOX-111'
rows = (1,1007)

current = os.getcwd()
filename = 'test.csv'
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
#print(current)
#print(filename)
print(filepath)

with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(readCSV, None)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row[16])
        row_count =sum(1 for row in readCSV)
        print(row_count)
with open(filepath, 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.readline())  # write out the 1st line
    for line in infile:
            cols = line.strip().split(',')
            cols[16] = project
            outfile.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')
with open('out.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in infile:
        if row % 2 != 0:
            cols [15] = parent
        outfile.write()
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Uhh... what are you trying to modify it to do? What's it currently do? Where specifically does it fall short? Does it give an error?

Comment: Suspicious last line: `outfile.write()`: didn't you forget `','.join(cols) + '\n'`? And why not using csv package to write the file since you're already using it to read csv stuff?

Comment: You read all the lines with a `csv.reader` to get the line count, and then you iterate again **without** a `csv.reader` when you are processing the data (???). And again without csv to write. What do you need to do. Maybe it can be done in only one iteration.

Comment: hi guys, sorry the program is a little bit of a mess, the first bit was to figure out how many rows are in the csv file. the second bit is to change the values in col 16 without effecting the header. the last bit is attempting to modify some of the values in col 15 every other line - this is where i've fallen down. Sorry for really not knowing what I'm doing here, I've been looking on the web all day trying to figure this out! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the row's index when comparing to `0`. Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

```
with open('out.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for rowidx,row in enumerate(infile):
        cols = row.strip().split(',')
        if rowidx % 2 != 0:
            cols[15] = parent
        outfile.write(cols)
```

You really should be using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module here, though. Untested but should get you started.

```
with open('out.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for rowidx,row in enumerate(reader):
        if rowidx % 2 != 0:
            row[15] = parent
        writer.write_row(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me last night and this is what they came up with:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.readline())  # write out the 1st line
    for line in infile:
        cols = line.strip().split(',')
        cols[16] = project
        outfile.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')

with open('out.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out1.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.readline())  # write out the 1st line
    lineCounter = 0
    for line in infile:
        lineCounter += 1
        cols = line.strip().split(',')
        if lineCounter % 2 != 0:
            cols[15] = parent
        outfile.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')
```